# What is this schematic symbol that is a circled capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, schematics, symbol

I am trying to determine what this symbol is that looks like a circled capacitor and is labeled as "Z1" that I circled in blue below.

[image]

Here is the full schematic with this component being near the top left at the input.

[image: This is the full schematic]

In my search I found [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/347930/anyone-recognise-this-capacitor-and-its-symbol-circle-with-dot) question with a circled capacitor and a dot but I'm not sure if its the same. I also found websites saying Z is for zener diodes which this obviously is not or [this](http://pcblibraries.com/forum/common-pcb-reference-designators_topic728.html) website that says Z could be for  a balun, general network, or phase shifter but I did not find circuit symbols that match this one when googling those.

Comment: *circled capacitor and a dot* - I don't see the dot.

Comment: With a dot I would assume a neon/gas-dicharge tube. Without I would not know. (Neon tube without gas????)

Comment: @Andyaka the dot is in the question in the link. For clarification mine does not have a dot which is why I don't think its the same as the one in the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are indeed varistors like others are (educatingly) guessing.

> Varistors Z1 and Z2 have overvoltage protect function on the line input.

Source: http://www.pavouk.org/hw/en_atxps.html

You can find this source by googling on ATX power supply using the website on the schematic.
Search term: `ATX POWER SUPPLY site:www.pavouk.org`

Answer (score 2):

It's likely an MOV (Metal Oxide Varistor) used for surge suppression. Context guides this answer - the schematic is from the late 1990's when this was a common use and it is across the hot/neutral lines and in the earth ground path.

Answer (score 1):

The "Z" reference designator strongly suggests that it is some kind of voltage-clamping device. It could be anything from a spark gap to a gas-dicharge tube to a semiconductor device such as a MOV or TVS. What does the parts list (bill of materials) say about it?

Comment: My guess from the symbol alone would be a gas discharge tube of some sort, since that's the closest to the symbol.

Comment: I don't see a BOM but the website I got the schematic from is this https://www.hardwaresecrets.com/anatomy-of-switching-power-supplies/2/

Comment: Well, since that site doesn't talk any further about that particular schematic -- the section on transient filtering uses a different schematic -- there's no way to know exactly what Z1 is.