# Neon lamp symbol

Tags: symbol, lamp, neon

I am new to neon lamps:

[image]

I just discovered its electronic symbol:

[image]

I am a little bit confused, What does the dot in the symbol mean? It looks like the neon lamp is polarized. How do I know what lead of the neon lamp corresponds to the dot?

I have seen other circuit schematics where they place the dot at the center:

[image]

Where do I place the dot, then? At the center or at one extreme?

Comment: According to [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/347930/anyone-recognise-this-capacitor-and-its-symbol-circle-with-dot), the dot doesn't indicate polarity, but indicates that the bulb is filled with a special gas. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Neon lamps are not polarised but only the more negative electrode will light up.

[image]

*Figure 1. Only the cathode lights up. +DC (left), -DC (center), AC (right) supplied to NE-2 type neon lamps. Source: Wikipedia [Neon lamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neon_lamp).*

For an AC supply the anode and cathode swap on each half-cycle of the AC supply so connection polarity doesn't matter.

[image]

*Figure 2. NE-2 type neon lamp powered by alternating current (AC). Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neon_lamp).*

The linked article may explain more.

> Where do I place the dot, then? At the center or at one extreme?

Either location of the dot should convey the meaning that it is a gas-filled lamp.

Comment: _"Yes, neon lamps are polarised ..."_ - I don't think that's true; it would mean the neon lights are asymmetrical, while as far as I know such indicator bulbs are symmetrical. If they were polarised, it should matter which way around they are connected to DC. Can you provide a reference that this is the case?

Comment: Maybe I can phrase it better. Figure 1 shows what happens when connected to DC. Only the cathode lights up and I provided the reference. How about, "*Yes, neon lamps are polarised in that only the cathode lights up. Their construction is symmetrical however and either side can act as cathode.*"?

Comment: I see what you mean, but I still don't think the components themselves are polarised... Perhaps something like "Neon lamps themselves are not polarised, but only the negative-connected terminal will light up."?

Comment: Whether you consider it polarized or not (which I don't), the dot is not to indicate polarity anyway--it's the symbol for a gas-filled (as opposed to vacuum) tube.

Comment: I think hearth's comment is worth including in the answer, as it explains why the dot is there (and indirectly, why its location isn't particularly important)

Comment: I did already, yesterday. See the last line of my answer.

Comment: @Transistor Nixi-tubes however are polarised, as only their numbers should glow. How would they be drawn? just wondering? great answer btw.

Comment: @Tech: [Lots of ways](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&sxsrf=ALeKk03FtTTX1s61DLYrAU9uIAMNUclORQ%3A1585042263933&source=hp&biw=1827&bih=960&ei=V9N5XqWNNorikgXgz7HoBg&q=nixie+schematic&oq=nixie+schematic&gs_l=img.3..0i8i30l4j0i24.354.8605..8754...9.0..0.115.1826.19j4......0....1..gws-wiz-img.......35i39j0j0i5i30._FS8jU5uad4&ved=0ahUKEwjllN_I5rLoAhUKsaQKHeBnDG0Q4dUDCAY&uact=5) apparently. I imagine that the "anode" would glow if connected backwards.

Answer (score 14):

The dot denotes a gas-filled tube, which distinguishes it from a normal vacuum tube. Neon bulbs and [voltage regulator tubes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage-regulator_tube)<sup>1</sup>, as well as certain types of high-power tubes such as [thyratrons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thyratron) and mercury-vapor rectifiers fall into this category.

The neon bulb is not polarized; it is symmetrical.

---

<sup>1</sup> See also [Anyone recognise this capacitor and its symbol (circle with dot)?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/347930/11683)

Comment: Neon bulbs may typically be designed symmetrically, but that doesn't necessarily imply that they're not polarized.  Video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vrmwql2msbU about a neon-opto-isolator-based meter demonstrates how some tubes can be sensitive to insertion direction in some circuits.

Answer (score 3):

A neon lamp is not polarised. It may be connected either way.

The dot signifies that it's a gas-filled lamp.